# Pegar um texto específico de um arquivo de texto utilizando PHP

Tags: php

Queria saber se tem como fazer para pegar um texto em específico de um arquivo txt usando o php ?

Eu já consigo fazer a leitura deste para exibir ele por completo como resultado em uma div, porém precisava pegar por exemplo uma palavra ou um número para exibir separado em outro local. Dá para fazer isso em PHP ou utilizando JavaScript ?

Abaixo está minha div onde apresenta os resultados que executam o script em PHP que faz a leitura do arquivo de texto:

```
<div id="box_results">
    <div id="results" class="results">
      <?php
        //Abrimos o arquivo em leitura
        $arquivo = 'log/speedtest.txt';
        $fp = fopen($arquivo, 'r');

        //Lemos o arquivo
        $texto = fread($fp, filesize($arquivo));

        //Transformamos as quebras de linha em etiquetas <br>
        $texto = nl2br($texto);

        echo $texto;
      ?>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

Pergunto isso porque este arquivo de texto é temporário, ele é gerado toda vez que um formulário é submetido, ou seja, ele atualiza as informações neste arquivo de texto. E para que os resultados sejam exibidos após a submissão de um formulário, utilizo o seguinte script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#frm").on("submit", function(){
    $("#results").html('');
    fun();
});

var t; 

function recarrega() {
    $("#box_results").load(" #results");
    $("#execute").hide();
} 

function fun() {
    t = setInterval(recarrega, 1000);
} 

function stop() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    $("#execute").show();
}
</script>
```

É possível pegar então um conteúdo específico após este arquivo de texto ser atualizado ?

**Edit**:

Este é o conteúdo do arquivo de texto que farei a leitura:

```
[Parâmetros]
CPU = 512
WAN = 1237
LAN1 = 435
```

Comment: Por mais estranha que parece ser essa solução de salvar o formulário em arquivo, mas não seria mais conveniente utilizar um padrão de texto estruturado como JSON, XML, CSV, etc?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Então, no caso eu não tenho muito conhecimento, e acabei por investir neste método que ainda assim tive ajuda para o fazer. E no caso não são informações sensíveis para serem gravadas no arquivo de texto então não tem problemas neste caso de elas serem exibidas.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Porém ainda neste caso, eu preciso descobrir se tem a possibilidade de fazer isso pois preciso fazer a leitura de outro tipo de informações, que no caso estas são de um teste de velocidade, eu precisava pegar informações como a CPU de um computador ou WAN que serão todas essas gravadas num arquivo de texto.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o `file_get_contents` junto com a função `strpos`.

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
if (strpos(file_get_contents($arquivo), 'palavra_a_ser_procurada') !== false)  {
  echo 'found';
}
```

- O `file_get_contents` transforma o texto do arquivo em uma string,
  podendo ser trabalhado normalmente como tal no PHP.
- O `strpos` serve para você encontrar a posição da primeira ocorrência
  de uma palavra dentro de uma string. Você consegue também verificar a
  posição que a string foi encontrada dentro do texto, conforme
  consegue ver no manual no link abaixo.
- Para pegar parte do texto você pode usar funções como o `substr()`.

Como você disse que vai pegar dados da máquina, como CPU, por exemplo, você pode criar uma função que identifique se encontra a palavra CPU dentro do arquivo e, se encontrar, ela informa a posição e com base nela você consegue pegar x letras a frente com o substr.

Manual das funções na página PHP para você entender melhor e conseguir montar seu código:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php

Comment: No caso tem como eu pegar um número no qual ele seja aleatório ? Pois como comentei acima com outro rapaz, será para um sistema onde terá um arquivo com um número seguido de um texto. Ex.: CPU = 512. Porém este número mudará conforme for atualizado este sistema, e eu precisava passar este número para uma URL.

Comment: Editei a resposta acrescentando informações. Mas, basicamente, sim, tem como. Mesmo com o valor sendo aleatório, o dado que você vai buscar ai não seria. Então vc pode procurar por CPU, ver a posição e ai pegar os próximos 3 dígitos contando 6 posições a frente, por exemplo

Comment: Interessante, será que você consegue montar o esquema pra mim, como sou aprendiz em PHP ainda, estou um pouco perdido? Tendo as informações contidas no arquivo de texto para poder pegar o que eu preciso e passar depois pro PHP ?

Comment: Fica difícil montar mais coisas do que isso considerando que não tenho o arquivo, mas a lógica está ali: faz um if pra checar se a palavra existe. Se existir ele pega a posição. Depois disso vc conta qts posições vai ter até o valor que você quer e ai vc exibe ele. A dica é saber quantos dígitos vc vai querer q exiba. Em "CPU=512" e C na posição 1, vc vai exibir 3 caracteres a partir da posição 5. Se você olhar os exemplos do manual ajuda a fazer também, entender mais cada função...

Comment: Editei a pergunta com os parâmetros que eu preciso fazer a leitura, agora esse código que você me passou, eu coloco ele dentro da função montada para fazer a leitura do arquivo de texto ? Onde eu posso colocar ?

Comment: Outra dúvida é, após conseguir encontrar o texto e pegar os números, eu consigo passar eles para uma URL ? como se fossem um ID de página sabe ?

Comment: Como eu coloquei ali e explica melhor no manual, o file_get_contents transforma o conteúdo do arquivo numa string, então você pode trabalhar com ele como tal normalmente, como outro texto qqr no seu php. Você pode armazenar ele numa variável e fazer o que quiser com ele...